NamedPipeClientStream getting data it sent echoed back
I have a simple service which communicates over named pipes.
This is what the client looks like:
internal class ServicePipeManager : IDisposable
{
    private NamedPipeClientStream pipe;
    private DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ServiceMessage), ServiceMessage.GatherSerializationTypes());
    private MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream();
    public void Connect()
    {
        pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyService", PipeDirection.InOut);
        pipe.Connect(100);
    }
    public ServiceResponse Send(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        request.MessageID = id;
        SendRequest(request);
        var length = pipe.ReadInt32();
        bufferStream.SetLength(length);
        bufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        pipe.Read(bufferStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
        var response = serializer.ReadObject(bufferStream);
        if (response is ExceptionResponse ex)
            ex.Exception.ToException().Rethrow();
        if (response is not ServiceResponse result)
            throw new Exception("Response type is not a ServiceResponse");
        if (result.MessageID != id)
            throw new Exception("Result messageID did not match request");
        return result;
    }
    private void SendRequest(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        bufferStream.SetLength(0);
        bufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        serializer.WriteObject(bufferStream, request);
        pipe.WriteInt32((int)bufferStream.Length);
        pipe.Write(bufferStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)bufferStream.Length);
    }
}

This is what the messages look like:
[DataContract]
public class ServiceMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MessageID { get; set; }
    public static List<Type> GatherSerializationTypes()
    {
        var result = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var type in typeof(ServicePipeManager).Assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DataContractAttribute>().Any())
                result.Add(type);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
[DataContract]
public abstract class ServiceRequest : ServiceMessage
{
    public abstract ServiceResponse HandleRequest(RequestState state);
}
[DataContract]
public abstract class ServiceResponse : ServiceMessage
{
}
[DataContract]
public class ExceptionResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public ExceptionSerializer Exception { get; set; }
}

This is what the service looks like:
public class Service
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(ListenerThread);
        thread.Start(null);
    }
    private void ListenerThread(object ignore)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var stream = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyService", PipeDirection.InOut, 100, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
                stream.WaitForConnection();
                var thread = new Thread(ProcessThread);
                thread.Start(stream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    private void ProcessThread(object streamAsObject)
    {
        var stream = streamAsObject as NamedPipeServerStream;
        if (stream == null)
            return;
        using (stream)
        try
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ServiceMessage), ServiceMessage.GatherSerializationTypes());
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            while (stream.IsConnected)
            {
                int length = stream.ReadInt32();
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ms.SetLength(length);
                stream.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
                var message = (ServiceRequest)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
                HandleMessage(serializer, stream, message, ms);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    public static void HandleMessage(
        DataContractSerializer serializer, NamedPipeServerStream stream,
        ServiceMessage message, MemoryStream buffer)
    {
        ServiceResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            var req = (ServiceRequest)message;
            var state = new RequestState(...);
            response = req.HandleRequest(state);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = new ExceptionResponse { Exception = ExceptionSerializer.FromException(ex) };
        }
        response.MessageID = message.MessageID;
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        buffer.SetLength(0);
        serializer.WriteObject(buffer, response);
        stream.WriteInt32((int)buffer.Length);
        stream.Write(buffer.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)buffer.Length);
    }
}

Occasionally, the service ends up in a state where the client just gets back out of the pipe what it sent in, instead of getting a proper response.  It throws the "Response type is not a ServiceResponse" exception because the data type it's getting back is ServiceRequest, not a ServiceResponse.  Given the simple nature of the code, I don't see any way that it could be sending back the same data it received.  Is there something about NamedPipeClientStream that behaves this way?  Or am I missing an obvious bug in my code?  ServiceRequest.HandleRequest has to return a ServiceResponse type, so I don't see any way for Service.HandleMessage() to send back a ServiceRequest.
